# Node's child_process.exec causes "command not found" on OSX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

If I run a command (psql) directly in the terminal, it works. But if I do `childProcess.exec('psql ...')`, it causes "/bin/sh: psql: command not found" on OSX. Both work on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I tried `whereis psql` and adding that to PATH, then `console.log(process.env.PATH)` and `childProcess.exec('echo $PATH')` both contain the psql directory, but I still get "command not found". It works if I do `childProcess.exec('/opt/homebrew/bin/psql ...')`, but I can't just hardcode every command's path.

What's going on here and how can I fix it? Is `childProcess.exec` ignoring PATH on OSX?